# nmap: no exact OS matches when adding the exact signature to nmap-os-db

Tags: network, nmap, network-scanners

I'm currently trying to learn Nmap -O (OS guess feature).
I'm launching the following command: `nmap -O 172.17.0.3`
This command is generating the following fingerprint as output:

```
    No exact OS matches for host (If you know what OS is running on it, see https://nmap.org/submit/ ).
TCP/IP fingerprint:
OS:SCAN(V=7.70%E=4%D=3/2%OT=8080%CT=1%CU=32738%PV=Y%DS=1%DC=D%G=Y%M=0000BC%
    OS:TM=64006E4C%P=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)SEQ(SP=105%GCD=1%ISR=109%TI=Z%CI=Z%TS=
    OS:A)OPS(O1=M5B4ST11NW7%O2=M5B4ST11NW7%O3=M5B4NNT11NW7%O4=M5B4ST11NW7%O5=M5
    OS:B4ST11NW7%O6=M5B4ST11)WIN(W1=FE88%W2=FE88%W3=FE88%W4=FE88%W5=FE88%W6=FE8
    OS:8)ECN(R=Y%DF=Y%T=40%W=FAF0%O=M5B4NNSNW7%CC=Y%Q=)T1(R=Y%DF=Y%T=40%S=O%A=S
    OS:+%F=AS%RD=0%Q=)T2(R=N)T3(R=N)T4(R=Y%DF=Y%T=40%W=0%S=A%A=Z%F=R%O=%RD=0%Q=
    OS:)T5(R=Y%DF=Y%T=40%W=0%S=Z%A=S+%F=AR%O=%RD=0%Q=)T6(R=Y%DF=Y%T=40%W=0%S=A%
    OS:A=Z%F=R%O=%RD=0%Q=)T7(R=Y%DF=Y%T=40%W=0%S=Z%A=S+%F=AR%O=%RD=0%Q=)U1(R=Y%
    OS:DF=N%T=40%IPL=164%UN=0%RIPL=G%RID=G%RIPCK=G%RUCK=G%RUD=G)IE(R=Y%DFI=N%T=
    OS:40%CD=S)
```

I took the output and formatted it like this:

```
# Test 
Fingerprint TestFinger
Class Siemens | embedded || specialized
CPE cpe:/h:test:test_001
SEQ(SP=106%GCD=1%ISR=10B%TI=Z%CI=Z%II=I%TS=A)
OPS(O1=M5B4ST11NW7%O2=M5B4ST11NW7%O3=M5B4NNT11NW7%O4=M5B4ST11NW7%O5=M5B4ST11NW7%O6=M5B4ST11)
WIN(W1=FE88%W2=FE88%W3=FE88%W4=FE88%W5=FE88%W6=FE88)
ECN(R=Y%DF=Y%T=40%W=FAF0%O=M5B4NNSNW7%CC=Y%Q=)
T1(R=Y%DF=Y%T=40%S=O%A=S+%F=AS%RD=0%Q=)
T2(R=N)
T3(R=N)
T4(R=Y%DF=Y%T=40%W=0%S=A%A=Z%F=R%O=%RD=0%Q=)
T5(R=Y%DF=Y%T=40%W=0%S=Z%A=S+%F=AR%O=%RD=0%Q=)
T6(R=Y%DF=Y%T=40%W=0%S=A%A=Z%F=R%O=%RD=0%Q=)
T7(R=Y%DF=Y%T=40%W=0%S=Z%A=S+%F=AR%O=%RD=0%Q=)
U1(R=Y%DF=N%T=40%IPL=164%UN=0%RIPL=G%RID=G%RIPCK=G%RUCK=G%RUD=G)
IE(R=Y%DFI=N%T=40%CD=S)
```

And I appended it to the nmap-os-db file.
When I re-run nmap was expecting nmap to tell me that the OS recognised was "TestFinger", but I got the same output as in the first run, as if nmap was ignoring the new entry in nmap-os-db.
I also tried inserting a random string in the nmap-os-db, in order to check whether nmap was actually using that file, and it was because it was giving me an error.

I'm sure I'm missing something really simple but I'm not able to figure it out, any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

First, a caveat - the instructions for doing this manually is sparse and your mileage may vary.

TL;DR - You're going to have to experiment a bit.  There are variances in the fingerprint returned on each scan.

I tried what you did, getting the fingerprint, adapting it, and adding it to the `nmap-os-db` file.  I used my laptop as the test host and received the same results.  It didn't recognize the host on the next pass.

There are subtle changes to the fingerprint output that needs to be taken into account when you create the entry in the `nmap-os-db` file.

As an example, I ran two `nmap -O localhost` scans in a row on my localhost (Mac OS X Ventura) and found the following difference:

The first run: `SEQ(SP=101%GCD=1%ISR=10C%TI=Z%CI=RI%TS=22)`
The second run: `SEQ(SP=FC%GCD=1%ISR=105%TI=Z%CI=RI%TS=21)`

Doing a little reverse engineering, I looked in the `nmap-os-db` file and saw the values in some fields like SP and ISR are ranges instead of single values.

When I created a new entry in the file with ranges it worked as expected.  Look at the SP and ISR fields below:

```
# MacOS Ventura 13.2.1
Fingerprint Apple Mac OS X Ventura 13.2.1
Class Apple | Mac OS X | 13.2.X | general purpose
CPE cpe:/o:apple:mac_os_x:13.2.1 auto
SEQ(SP=EF-107%GCD=1%ISR=F7-10D%TI=Z%CI=RI%TS=21)
<the rest deleted for brevity>
```

I noticed the TS field varies as well but that didn't affect the OS identification, so like I said at the beginning you'll need to experiment a bit.

Also, I'm not sure how to determine the correct ranges.  I'd need to dig through the code to figure that out.

**References**
[Nmap source](https://github.com/nmap/nmap)
[Nmap OS Detection](https://nmap.org/book/osdetect.html)